# need to get value from json in sh based upon another value

Tags: json, bash

I am trying to do something with a EC2 spot fleet request.  I need to extract the SpotFleetRequestId based upon the passed in value of ImageId.  I can't figure it out.  Can anyone help?  Here is the json:

```
{
```

"SpotFleetRequestConfigs": [
      {
          "SpotFleetRequestId": "sfr-73fbd2ce-aa30-494c-8788-1cee4EXAMPLE",
          "SpotFleetRequestConfig": {
              "TargetCapacity": 20,
              "LaunchSpecifications": [
                  {
                      "EbsOptimized": false,
                      "NetworkInterfaces": [
                          {
                              "SubnetId": "subnet-a61dafcf",
                              "DeviceIndex": 0,
                              "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                              "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
                              "SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount": 0
                          }
                      ],
                      "InstanceType": "cc2.8xlarge",
                      "ImageId": "ami-1a2b3c4d"
                  },
                  {
                      "EbsOptimized": false,
                      "NetworkInterfaces": [
                          {
                              "SubnetId": "subnet-a61dafcf",
                              "DeviceIndex": 0,
                              "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                              "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
                              "SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount": 0
                          }
                      ],
                      "InstanceType": "r3.8xlarge",
                      "ImageId": "ami-1a2b3c4d"
                  }
              ],
              "SpotPrice": "0.05",
              "IamFleetRole": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-spot-fleet-role"
          },
          "SpotFleetRequestState": "active"
      },
      {
          "SpotFleetRequestId": "sfr-306341ed-9739-402e-881b-ce47bEXAMPLE",
          "SpotFleetRequestConfig": {
              "TargetCapacity": 20,
              "LaunchSpecifications": [
                  {
                      "EbsOptimized": false,
                      "NetworkInterfaces": [
                          {
                              "SubnetId": "subnet-6e7f829e",
                              "DeviceIndex": 0,
                              "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                              "AssociatePublicIpAddress": true,
                              "SecondaryPrivateIpAddressCount": 0
                          }
                      ],
                      "InstanceType": "m3.medium",
                      "ImageId": "ami-1a2b3c4d"
                  }
              ],
              "SpotPrice": "0.05",
              "IamFleetRole": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-spot-fleet-role"
          },
          "SpotFleetRequestState": "active"
      }
  ]
}

Comment: I would suggest you use right tool for json handling like jq

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but this:

```
echo "$json" | grep -o '\(SpotFleetRequestId\|ImageId\): [0-9A-Za-z-]\+' | uniq
```

Produces this:

```
SpotFleetRequestId: sfr-73fbd2ce-aa30-494c-8788-1cee4EXAMPLE
ImageId: ami-1a2b3c4d
SpotFleetRequestId: sfr-306341ed-9739-402e-881b-ce47bEXAMPLE
ImageId: ami-1a2b3c4d
```